# Is there a term for two functions with equivalent change at each point?

Tags: functions, terminology

Suppose that I have two functions, $f(x)$ and $g(x)$, and that if $f(b) > f(a)$, then $g(b) > g(a)$. Similarly for $=$ and $<$. Or to put it another way, $\forall{a,b}: relation(f(a),f(b)) = relation(g(a),g(b))$. This property would be met by any pair of constant functions, any pair of monotonically increasing functions, and any pair of monotonically decreasing functions.

Is there a term for this?

(To be very specific, I wish to state that for any two points on a sphere, the chord length and the geodesic arc length are equivalent in this sense. I could use either metric if I wanted, say, to maximize the distance between this geodesic arc and some third point on the sphere.)